# C code that asks for inputs for a 3d array and then prints them in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, c

user-input array:

```
arr1[2][3][3]
```

printed array:

```
arr2[3][6]
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,k;                     //variables for nested for loops
    int d1 = 0;
    int d2 = 0;
    int arr1[2][3][3];              //array declaration
    int arr2[3][6];                 //array declaration
    printf("enter the values in the array: \n");
    for(i=1;i<=2;i++)              //represents block
    {
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++)          //represents rows
        {
            for(k=1;k<=3;k++)      //represents columns
            {
                printf("the value at arr[%d][%d][%d]: ",i,j,k);
                scanf("%d",&arr1[i][j][k]);
                arr2[d1 + j][d2 + k] = arr1[i][j][k];
            }
        }
        d1 = (d1 + j == 3) ? 0 : d1 + j;
        d2 = (d2 + k == 6) ? 0 : d2 + k;

    }

    printf("printing the values in array: \n");
    for(j=1;j<=3;j++)
    {
        for(k=1;k<=6;k++)
        {
                printf("%d ",arr2[j][k]);
                if(k==6)
                {
                    printf("\n");
                }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it it prints values that weren't inputed and I get a stack smashing error. I don't understand why, I want the 2 "layers" to print next to each other... but that's clearly not happening. I'm new to coding sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: I didn't go through the entire code but let's begin with: C arrays are 0-based.

Comment: Yep, all the indices are running right off the end of the array.

Comment: @paddy I don't know what that means

Comment: @Ally it means that you need to change the range of your loop variables. for the first loop, for example, you need to do ```for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)```. if you declare an array like ```int arr[2]```. then you can only access the first two elements, ```arr[0]``` and ```arr[1]```.

Comment: Imagine you're standing on top of a cliff. You can take 2 steps to get to the edge. That means there are 3 positions: Your starting position (position zero), the first step, and the second step. If you take three steps, you fall off the cliff.

Comment: @Ally As mentioned, if an array dimension is declared with size `n`, then the valid indices are `0` through `n-1`, inclusive.  So you would typically write `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` to iterate over the valid indices.  Note that most modern computer languages use zero-based array indexing, but there are exceptions that use one-based array indexing.  There are also many older languages that use one-based indexing.